# Find all solutions to the equation $(z−3+2i)^4 = z^4$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all solutions to the equation $(z−3+2i)^4 = z^4$

I am confused, does not $z$ cancels out and leaves me with $-3+2i=0$ but I have to use de Moivre theorem to find all solutions.

Comment: why would z cancel out? $ (z + a)^4=z^4\implies 4z^3a + 6z^2a^2+4za^3 + a^4 = 0$.  Which is not a good way to do solve it but the $z$s don't cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\dfrac{z-3+2i}z\right)^4=1=e^{2n\pi i}$$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies\dfrac{z-3+2i}z=e^{2n\pi i/4}$ where $n=0,1,2,3$

Comment: For the OP to notice and justify: why is it possible to divide by $\;z\;$ ? +1

Comment: I am still confused, usually we convert an equation to polar form and then apply de moivre theorem. for example in this case, -3+2i can be replaced with anything with format -a+bi any it would not make a difference, is it true?

Comment: i'm not sure how to go about solving this question using De Moire's equation.

Comment: @Sammantha, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers